# XSLT formatting numbers, insert '-' after every 4 digits starting from the right most digit

Tags: xslt, numbers, format

I have a number that's 27 digits long, I need to format for readability purposes as below :

```
Input : 999967799857791961574987365

Expected output : 999-9677-9985-7791-9615-7498-7365
```

So in words, ***Starting from the right most, I need to insert a '-' after every 4 digits***.

I have been using

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($ID, '###-####-####-####-####-####-####-####')" />
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Any help or pointers would be great..Cheers

Comment: Are you using XSLT1 or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't just pass in the format string as you did and have it work is that the characters in the format string all have a special significance. The "-" is understood as the minus sign, not as a grouping separator. To make it work, you have to define a format using xsl:decimal-format and reference it using the optional third argument to format-number. Here's a complete stylesheet you can call on any XML file to illustrate:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:decimal-format name="dashes" grouping-separator="-"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(999967799857791961574987365,
                                        '-####', 'dashes')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I knew there was a less hacky way. +1

Comment: Thanks @Shaun , Adding decimal format did the trick,I had to make a slight modification:
My final code as it stands is below :        
            `<xsl:value-of select='concat($RECEIPT_ID_PREFIX," ",format-number($RECEIPT_ID_UNFORMATTED,"###-####-####-####-####-####-####-####", "dashes"))'/>`         
**However the last 10 digits of String I get after formatting are different from the ones I pass.** 
`Input : 11192878690839099**9898961410**`
`Output :  111-9287-8690-8390-99**57-6890-1632**`
Any pointers as to why thats happening ?
PS:Sorry cant seem to get the formatting right in comment sect

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a hack to me, but you could try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(format-number($ID,',####'),',','-')"/>
```

This worked in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 for me.

Note: `$ID` must be an integer. You may need to use `xs:integer($ID)` (which may require a 2.0 processor).

---

Answer to comment:

Try this template instead:

```
<xsl:template name="ReceiptId">
    <xsl:param name="RECEIPT_ID_UNFORMATTED"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RECEIPT_ID_FORMATTED" select="translate(format-number(xs:integer($RECEIPT_ID_UNFORMATTED),',####'),',','-')"/>
    <div class="line">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($RECEIPT_ID_PREFIX,&quot; &quot;,$RECEIPT_ID_FORMATTED)"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Don't forget to declare the `xs` namespace in the `xsl:stylesheet` (`xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`) so you can use `xs:integer()`

Comment: Thanks for the response @Daniel Haley. I tried the tip as below    `<xsl:template name="ReceiptId" >  
     <xsl:param name="RECEIPT_ID_UNFORMATTED" />  
     <xsl:variable name="RECEIPT_ID_FORMATTED" value="translate(format-number($RECEIPT_ID_UNFORMATTED,',####'),',','-')"/>  
     <div class="line">  
      <xsl:value-of select='concat($RECEIPT_ID_PREFIX," ",$RECEIPT_ID_FORMATTED)' />  
     </div>  
</xsl:template>`  
It throws me a Style sheet error. I tried converting it to an Integer,throws an exception.Can you please take a look at above code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Sandeep - Please see my edit. You had `value` instead of `select` in `xsl:variable`. I'm also assuming you have `$RECEIPT_ID_PREFIX` declared somewhere else in your stylesheet.

Comment: Yes, RECEIPT_ID_PREFIX is declares else where, @Daniel, looks like I was wrong about the XSLT version I was using,found out we r using XSLT 1.0 at my work and not 2.0 as I was originally told. Is there a replacement for `xs:integer()` in XSLT 1.0 ? I tried `number()` doesnt work, any other alternatives?..I will give it a try tomorrow..thanks