# XSL formatting number with 'hyphens' every two digits

Tags: xslt, numbers, format

I have searched for days and found one example [here][1]

[1]: [XSLT formatting numbers, insert '-' after every 4 digits starting from the right most digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579546/xslt-formatting-numbers-insert-after-every-4-digits-starting-from-the-right),  but it doesn't seem to work out as expected.

Here is what I need to happen.  I have a number that is 7 digits like '1122334' and I need to coerce it to '11-22-33-4'.

Here is my code so far:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/dataset">
      <xsl:decimal-format name="dashes" grouping-separator='-'/>
      <dataset>
         <!-- Nullify (0040,A043) Concept Name Code Sequence -->
        <attr tag="0040A043" vr="SQ"/>
      </dataset>
      <dataset>
       <xsl:variable name="modPatientID" select="attr[@tag='00100020']"/>
       <xsl:variable name="AccNum" select="attr[@tag='00080050']"/>
         <xsl:if test="string-length($modPatientID)=7">
           <xsl:if test="contains(attr[@tag='00080050'],'_')">
             <!-- (0008,0050) Accession_Number -->
             <attr tag="00100020" vr="LO">
               <xsl:value-of select="format-number($modPatientID, '##-##-##-#','dashes')"/>
             </attr>
            </xsl:if>
           </xsl:if>
          </dataset>
         </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I get back is '1-1-2-2-3-3-4' and I want it to look like '11-22-33-4'

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?  If possible I would like to continue using the 'format-number' function.

thank you

-frustrated

Comment: Can you show your source XML? Is that your working XSL file? `<xsl:decimal-format>` should be top level. I think it won't even compile if it is inside a `template`. Try replacing $modPatientID with '1122334'. Does it work as expected?

Comment: no luck yet - This is my working XSL file.  I moved <xsl:decimal-format> to the top level (above the template) and it still had no affect.  The output was still '1-1-2-2-3-3-4'  I left this change in place and then I tried replacing $modPatientID with '1122334' and the output was still '1-1-2-2-3-3-4'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a number that is 7 digits like '1122334' and I need to coerce
>   it to '11-22-33-4'.

Here's one way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
   substring($modPatientID, 1, 2), '-', 
   substring($modPatientID, 3, 2), '-' , 
   substring($modPatientID, 5, 2), '-' ,
   substring($modPatientID, 7)
)"/>
```

<s>Here's another:</s>
**---Don't use this - see my edit #2 below---**

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
   format-number(substring($modPatientID, 1, 6), '-##', 'dashes'), '-', 
   substring($modPatientID, 7)
)"/>
```

---

**Edit:**
<s>Here's a third one, which is merely a correction of what was suggested by @helderdarocha:</s>
**---Don't use this - see my edit #2 below---**

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(format-number(concat($modPatientID, 0), '-##', 'dashes'), 1, 10)"/>
```

---

## **EDIT 2:**

This should have occurred to me right from the start: **your PatientID is not a number** and you shouldn't try applying number formatting to it. Otherwise you will lose any leading zeros the "number" might have.

Comment: okay, losing any leading zeros would not be good.  I'll try your first way to doing it tomorrow.

Comment: Okay- I couldn't wait.  I used your 1st method and it worked as well.  Thanks for thinking about the leading zeros!  It would have been a real nightmare.

Comment: lol, actually I have just run into this where the 'leading zero' was dropped before it was handed over to me, and now I need to add it back and also format it with hyphens, but I'll ask another question and refer to this one.  The Patient ID was six digits long and it should actually be seven with the leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str:split template from http://www.exslt.org/str/index.html.

I just tested your sample input '1122334' and it works fine.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    extension-element-prefixes="str func exsl">
    <xsl:import href="str.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div>
            <xsl:variable name="num">1122334</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="str:split($num, '')">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2) = 0 and (position() != last())">-</xsl:if>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this stylesheet, with any source:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:decimal-format name="dashes" grouping-separator='-'/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number('1122334', '##-##-##-#','dashes')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does it print `11-22-33-4`? If not, it reveals something about the transformer you are using (probably Xalan or Saxon 6.5.5). In that case it won't make any difference if you use `##-##-##-#` or simply `-#`, since the grouping separator is only read once, from the right.

You can try `-##` and you will have your number in groups of two.

Saxon 9 prints the number the way you expected (which is surprising to me). If you can't use it as your XSL processor, you can try the hack below:

<strike>`<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(format-number(concat('1122334','0'), '-##','dashes'), '0')"/>`</strike>

<strike>I added a `0`, formatted the number in groups of 2, and then removed the `0`.</strike>

**Edit**: That was a bad hack. @michael.hor257k rightly observed that it would fail as soon as a number with a zero was inserted. So instead of `substring-before` use `substring` as suggested in his solution:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(format-number(concat('1122334', 0), '-##', 'dashes'), 1, 10)"/>
```

Comment: "*I added a 0, formatted the number in groups of 2, and then removed the 0.*" Try it with '1120334'.

Comment: So, I tried running the stylesheet above and the output was '1-1-2-2-3-3-4', so its my transformer - thanks for the explanation as I couldn't figure out it was reading right to left.  I also tried the hack you supplied with my original SS (I commented out the offending 'format-number' line from my copy), pasted it into the correct spot and the output was '1'.  :-/  http://pastebin.com/RhP23hTM - I tried with the variable name and with a 'real' number.

Comment: Oops. @michael.hor257k is right :) There's a bug in this solution. But you can use `substring` and get the string until the length-1.

Comment: He fixed it in his solution as well :)

Comment: If I try it with '1122334' it comes back with '1' & that is using the hack that helderdarocha posted above.

Comment: Try michael's solutions. Se if any of them works for you. I wasn't able to reproduce your error here.

Comment: I see @michael.hor257k answer now - I used his fix for your 'hack'.  Works as expected and I'm a happy camper!  Thanks you two!

Comment: @Docjay No, no, no - see the second edit to my post.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, I get an error because the xsl:decimal-format is within the xsl:template; it should be outside. When I fix that it works for me (in Saxon 9.5).

But I agree, treating a patient ID as a number is not good.

I have no end of trouble with my spreadsheet software treating VAT numbers as numeric because they are all-digits, and thus losing any leading zeroes.